# Kindly help to write SQL queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I need your help to write two SQL queries (DB Oracle) to fetch data. Both table has huge data so need to take care of the performance also. Below is the scenario -

There are two tables `Department (DEPT)` and `Employee (EMP)`. They have a **1 (DEPT) : M (EMP)** relationship.

`Department` table has columns

```
Row_id, DeptNm, Created_date
```

`Employee` table has columns

```
Row_id, EMPName, Emp_num, Par_row_id (FK to DEPT.row_Id), Salary
```

For a specific `Department`, sort data per employee's decreasing salary and rank it. Data should be shown like this:

```
DeptNm  | EmpNm    | Salary | Rank              
--------------------------------
Finance | Vikram   | 200000 | 1                     
Finance | Uttaam   | 150000 | 2  
Finance | Rajeev   | 100000 | 3  
ITDPPT  | Balaajii | 150000 | 1  
ITDEPT  | Harsha   | 120000 | 2  
ITDEPT  | Weeniji  | 100000 | 3
```

Query that to show the data highest salary for a department. Data should be as -

```
 Dept_Nm   |       EMP_NM |   Salary   
   Finance |   Vikramadit |  2000000  
   ITDEPT  |       Balaji |  1500000
```

Comment: So have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: Use row_number for the first query. For the second filter out the rows with rank 1 from output of 1st query

Comment: I tired rownum but it always rank like 1,2,3,4....N. It will not rank it as 1,2,3, 1,2...if you see the resulted data for 1st requirement it is ranked as per the highest salary as per the department. So if we can use rownum in any otherway to get the desired output please help me to get that.

Comment: Replaced the `sql-server` tag (which stands for **Microsoft SQL Server**) with `oracle` since you specifically said this was for Oracle.....

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from (
  select dp.deptname,
         emp.empname,
         emp.salary, 
         dense_rank() over (partition by dp.deptname order by emp.salary desc) as rnk
  from employee emp
    join department dp on dp.row_id = emp.par_row_id 
) t
where rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this will help you please put Rank as I didn't get what process you want if you want dynamic Rank than try any "temp" variable.

```
select D.DeptName,E.EmpName,E.Salary from Employee E
lefe join Department as D on D.Par_Row_Id=E.Row_Id order by E.Salaray DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select D.DeptName,E.EmpName,E.Salary from Employee E
left join Department as D on D.Par_Row_Id=E.Row_Id order by E.Salaray DESC
```